# Using Puma and Sidekiq in a backend Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, puma

I have a backend Rails server with `Sidekiq`, which serves as API server. The app works as follow:

1. My Rails server receives many requests from incoming API clients at the same time.
2. For each of these requests, the Rails server will allocate jobs to a Sidekiq server. Sidekiq server makes requests to external APIs (such as Facebook) to get data, and analyze it and return a result to Rails server.

For example, if I receive 10 incoming requests from my API clients, for each request, I need to make 10 requests to external API servers, get data and process it.

My challenge is to make my app responds to incoming requests concurrently. That is, for each incoming request, my app should process in parallel: make calls to external APIs, get data and return result.

Now, I know that Puma can add concurrency to Rails app, while Sidekiq is multi-threaded.

My question is: Do I really need Sidekiq if I already have Puma? What would be the benefit of using both Puma and Sidekiq?

In particular, with Puma, I just invoke my external API calls, data processing etc. from my Rails app, and they will automatically be concurrent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you probably do want to use Puma and Sidekiq.  There are really two issues at play here.

Concurrency (as it seems you already know) is the number of web requests that can be handled simultaneously.  Using an app server like Puma or Unicorn will definitely help you get better concurrency than the default web brick server.

The other issue at play is the length of time that it takes your server to process a web request.

The reason that these two things are related is that number or requests per second that your app can process is a function of both the average processing time for each request and the number of worker processes that are accepting requests.  Say your average response time is 100ms.  Then a single web worker can process 10 requests per second.  If you have 5 workers, then you can handle 50 requests per second.  If your average response time is 500ms, then you can handle 2 reqs/sec with a single worker, and 10 reqs/sec with 5 workers.

Interacting with external APIs can be slow at times, and in the worst cases it can be very unreliable with unresponsive servers on the remote end, or network outages or slowdowns.  Sidekiq is a great way to insulate your application (and your end users) from the possibility that the remote API is responding slowly.  Imagine that the remote API is running slowly for some reason and that the average response time from it has slowed down to 2 seconds per request.  In that case you'd only be able to handle 2.5 reqs/sec with 5 workers.  With anymore traffic than that your end users might start to have a long wait time before any page on your app could respond, even those that don't make remote API calls, because all of your web workers might be waiting for the slow remote API to respond.  As traffic continues to increase your users would start getting connection timeouts.

The idea with using Sidekiq is that you separate the time spent waiting on the external API from your web workers.  You'd basically take the request for data from your user, pass it to Sidekiq, and then immediately return a response to the user that basically says "we're processing your request".  Sidekiq can then pick up the job and make the external request.  After it has the data it can save that data back into your application.  Then you can use web sockets to push a notification to the user that the data is ready.  Or even push the data directly to them and update the page accordingly.  (You could also use polling to have the page continually asking "is it ready yet?", but that gets very inefficient very quickly.)

I hope this makes sense.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jeremy. It makes a lot of sense. My process takes one to two mintes to pull data from external APIs. My concern is that resources of my workers are locked up while waiting for data from APIs. Does Sidekiq help me solve this problem?

Comment: Yeah, Sidekiq would help with that.  The last long paragraph of my answer is the description of how that would work.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I got that part. My question is: even if my Sidekiq creates multiple threads and waits for responses from external APIs, will these threads still hold resources (CPU, RAM) for several minutes while waiting? I speculate that if my app can run asynchronously, then while waiting for response, my server resources can be used to make other requests, or to process data returned from earlier requests.

Comment: The answer to that question largely depends on how the external API calls work.  If you can just fire a request to them and then they immediately return a "we're handling your request" message, then they `POST` the results to a web hook on your end, then yes, you should be able to do other things while waiting.  If you send a request and their service blocks until it has data ready to return directly to the same request, then your worker will still be consuming resources while waiting.

Answer (score 4):

Sidekiq, like Resque and Delayed Job, is designed to provide asynchronous job processing from a queue.

If you don't need jobs to be queued up and run asynchronously, there's no substantial benefit (or harm) to using Sidekiq.

If the tasks need to run synchronously (which it sounds like you might—it's not clear if clients are waiting for data or just requesting that jobs run), Sidekiq and its relatives are likely the wrong tool for the job. There is no guaranteed processing time when using Sidekiq or other solutions; jobs are pushed onto the end of the stack, however long that may be, and won't be processed until their turn comes up. If clients are waiting for data, they may time out *long* before your worker pool ever processes their jobs.

Comment: Thanks @colinm. My clients are waiting for data. Typically, it takes a coule of minutes for my workers to return result to clients. However, clients can send multiple requests at once. I would like to kick off data processing for each of the requests in parallel and return to clients whatever returned from my Sidekiq server. What would be a good solution for my situation?  Thank you your your insight.

Comment: More than 750 ms? Async.